# Converting an method from objective c to swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Hi guys how can i convert this code into swift.

```
 (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                   animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                  toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
}
```

I have been trying to figure it out but cant.

Thanks in advance
Aryan

Answer (score 2):

[Apple already did that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController:) for you:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
   animationControllerForOperation operation: UINavigationControllerOperation,
                fromViewController fromVC: UIViewController,
                  toViewController toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning?
{
}
```